# Select Option 1 to Select Option 2 and view the result (text) in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

Does anyone know how to actually display the `text` value from multiple dependent select fields?

I need option 1 to list a set of parent options. When an Option 1 is selected, it will determine the values available in Option 2 select field.

I then want the `text` value associated with the selected option to be displayed below the select field.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <panel class="main-content">
      <div>
        <b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="options" class="mb-3" />
        <div>Selected: <strong>{{ selected }}</strong></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="options" class="mb-3" />
        <div>Selected: <strong>{{ selected }}</strong></div>
      </div>
    </panel>

  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      selected: null,
      options: [
        { value: null, name: 'opt', text: 'Select One' },
        { value: 'option1', name: 'mys', text: 'Carbohydrates' },
        { value: 'option2', name: 'hkong', text: 'Fibre' },
        { value: 'option3', name: 'spore', text: 'Fat' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Kindly assist since it's something new for me in VueJs.

Comment: In Option 2, will there be a subset of options available to the user?

Comment: @MarvinWordWeaverParsons I don't get your question... but after select option 2, teh result will be displayed... the result is different based on option 1 and option 2...

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought you meant. What I would suggest is building those `Option2` options as a nested array or object in of each`options` Object. Then listen to the change event and set `selected` to the nested Object inside the selected option. I will work on putting together and answer that shows this. Give me a few.

Comment: Ok, I think I have got the logic you were looking for squared away. It is giving you the ability to create two separate select fields, where the second displays options based on what was selected in the first one. The browser then displays the TEXT value of the option selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is working in VueJS (tested). I was a little off about how the b-form-select element works, but this will give you the results you need.

If you are building the options manually, maybe just make a JSON file or a Component that returns these sets of options and subOptions and import it rather than putting all the options into your template (Cleaner Code).

```js
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      option1Selected: null,
      option2Selected: null,
      options: [
        {
          value: null,
          name: 'opt',
          text: 'Select One',
        },
        {
          value: 'option1',
          name: 'mys',
          text:'Carbohydrates',
        },
        {
          value: 'option2',
          name: 'hkong',
          text: 'Fibre',
        },
        {
          value: 'option3',
          name: 'spore',
          text: 'Fat',
        },
      ],
      subOptions: {
        option1: [
          {
            value: null,
            name: 'opt',
            text: 'Select One',
          },
          {
            value: 'option1-1',
            name: 'o1-1Name',
            text: 'Option 1-1 Text',
          },
          {
            value: 'option1-2',
            name: 'o1-2Name',
            text: 'Option 1-2 Text',
          },
          {
            value: 'option1-3',
            name: 'o1-3Name',
            text: 'Option 1-3 Text',
          },
        ],
        option2: [
          {
            value: null,
            name: 'opt',
            text: 'Select One',
          },
          {
            value: 'option2-1',
            name: 'o2-1Name',
            text: 'Option 2-1 Text',
          },
          {
            value: 'option2-2',
            name: 'o2-2Name',
            text: 'Option 2-2 Text',
          },
          {
            value: 'option2-3',
            name: 'o2-3Name',
            text: 'Option 2-3 Text',
          },
        ],
        option3: [
          {
            value: null,
            name: 'opt',
            text: 'Select One',
          },
          {
            value: 'option3-1',
            name: 'o3-1Name',
            text: 'Option 3-1 Text',
          },
          {
            value: 'option3-2',
            name: 'o3-2Name',
            text: 'Option 3-2 Text',
          },
          {
            value: 'option3-3',
            name: 'o3-3Name',
            text: 'Option 3-3 Text',
          },
        ],
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    option1text () {
      for (const key in this.options) {
        if (this.options[key].value === this.option1Selected) {
          return this.options[key].text;
        }
      }
    },
    option2text () {
      if (this.option1Selected != null) {
        for (const key in this.subOptions[this.option1Selected]) {
          if (this.subOptions[this.option1Selected][key].value === this.option2Selected) {
            return this.subOptions[this.option1Selected][key].text;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <panel class="main-content">
      <div>
        <b-form-select v-model="option1Selected" :options="options" class="mb-3" />
        <div>Selected: <strong>{{ option1text }}</strong></div>
      </div>
      <div v-if="option1Selected != null">
        <b-form-select v-model="option2Selected" :options="subOptions[option1Selected]" class="mb-3" />
        <div>Selected: <strong>{{ option2text }}</strong></div>
      </div>
    </panel>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Note I have updated code to properly reflect exactly what you were asking for in the question: the Text value of the option.**